# Awesomium - How can I get HTML source with frameset

Tags: vb.net, awesomium

I want to get HTML source to analysis the web page.
So, I use the code like this:

(Work.URL is just String variable in structure)

```
Dim View As WebView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1000, 600, WebCore.Sessions.Last())
View.Source = New Uri(Work.URL)

AddHandler View.LoadingFrameComplete, Sub(sender As Object, e As FrameEventArgs)
    If Not e.IsMainFrame Then Exit Sub
    Console.WriteLine(View.HTML)
End Sub
```

The code is work well. And Sample Result:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <frameset cols="*,*">
        <frame src="test1.html" />
        <frame src="test2.html" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

But, I want to get HTML source within frameset like this:

(Like Chrome Developer Tool)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <frameset cols="*,*">
        <frame src="test1.html">
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    ...
                </head>
                <body>
                    This page is TEST1.
                </body>
            </html>
        </frame>
        <frame src="test2.html">
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    ...
                </head>
                <body>
                    This page is TEST2.
                </body>
            </html>
        </frame>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

How can I get HTML source?

Comment: Why do you need Awesomium to "get HTML source to analysis the web page" ?

Comment: @voytek I want to check that the page have a media like YouTube, Vimeo.

Comment: And get ratio of HTML tags like "<span> : 15%"

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to get source code:

```
string source = webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
```

or.. you can try this

```
string source = webControl.HTML;
```

EDIT: remember when using `webControl.HTML`, you need to wait till document is loaded: `DocumentReadyState.Loaded`

Answer (score 0):

This is a build in function, that gives you the static html code that was set when loading the page. The timing for this one is crutial:

```
 webControl.HTML;
```

This function uses javascript to get the actual, dynamic source code of the page. This is what you would see in FireBug:

```
 webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
```

I prefer:

```
 form.webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```

I also read, that they are working on a "source" property that will hide the timing issues and will hopefully give the real html.